# Crashed while installing updates, won't boot

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a Toshiba Satellite. It crashed while installing updates and now it won't boot. All I get is a screen with 
*GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2-36ubuntu3.17* 
at the top of the page, with a few options below which do not seem to offer anything that will repair the damage.

Is it possible to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: An aborted upgrade is sometimes easy to recover from, sometimes very very hard. It depends upon what was being upgraded at the time and your skill level. My usual recommendation for non-experts is to boot from a LiveUSB, backup your data, and then do a clean-install.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which is much appreciated. "Non-expert" is an accurate description of my computer know-how. I will try your advice, but I am using a Chromebook and can not find any directions for creating a Ubuntu LiveUSB for that, and it may not be possible. I'll find out soon enough. Thanks again.